# How to duplicate a MySQL-populated select-element?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

**Summary:** I have a select-list populated with entries from MySQL. Now I want to duplicate the list and the entries "onclick". How can I duplicate the list with its entries?

**What I have**

```
<select name="acclist" id="acclist" class="acc_list">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
  <?php       
    $sql1="SELECT * FROM accounts";
        $results=$con->query($sql1); 
    while($rs=$results->fetch_assoc()) { 
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rs["number"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["name"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

This is the code to populate a select-tag with options from my MySQL-table.

**What I want to do**
On click a user should get another select, on another click another select and so on. Every select should be equal to the one I already have. So not only duplicating the select-tag, but also the options with values from the table.

**Question**
How can I duplicate a select-element populated with MySQL-entries?

I tried with JS, but I only get a single row.

```
function populate(selector) {
  $(selector)
    .append('<option value="<?echo $row0[1]; ?>"><? echo $row0[2]; ?></option>')
//    .append('<option value="bar">bar</option>')
}

populate('.myselect');
```

Is there another way to solve it or where is the mistake I make?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: I have added a short clarification, Mehdi.

Comment: You mean get the whole `select` element and insert it somewhere else in the page?

Comment: Yes, including the options which I have inserted with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to clone the `select` node with the `deep` parameter set to `true` so that its contents are also cloned. Then, you can simply add the clone to your form:

**Code:**

```
var
   node = document.getElementById("acclist"),
   clone = node.cloneNode(true);

/* Insert the node to the DOM. */
node.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
/* -- JavaScript -- */
function duplicate () {
  var
    node = document.getElementById("acclist"),
    clone = node.cloneNode(true);

  /* Insert the node to the DOM. */
  node.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}


/* Add the event listener to the 'click' event of the button. */
document.getElementById("duplicate").addEventListener("click", duplicate);
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<button id = "duplicate">Duplicate</button>
<select name="acclist" id="acclist" class="acc_list">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="1">Country 1</option>
  <option value="2">Country 2</option>
  <option value="3">Country 3</option>
</select>
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Event listeners that may be attached to the original `select` don't carry over to the cloned elements. In such a scenario, you'll have to use event delegation *(for [`JavaScript`](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) & [`jQuery`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/))*.
2. Beware the duplicate ids when cloning elements.